# TV drama future time traveller hiding in present times (1980s)

Tags: story-identification

Inspired by this story [Help identifying story where time traveler is identified because he doesn't hitch his pant leg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155271/help-identifying-story-where-time-traveler-is-identified-because-he-doesnt-hitc/155287#155287).

I remember watching a similar show in the 1980s on UK television.

A time traveller and his wife (maybe his family as well) were hiding in the present time 1980s from some kind of future enforcement.

I remember he wore a wide brimmed black hat and spent a lot of time huddled over a cauldron full of water. I think something to do with the water eddying in a certain way when a time portal activated nearby - he was forever trying to keep alert and watch for this.

I can't remember what exactly happened but somehow they get caught.

**UPDATE**!
A friend of mine claims that this featured eighties singer Adam Ant in one of his many minor acting roles when he tried to change career. Sadly he can't recall any further info. I've been searching but no joy (using terms like time travel and Adam Ant invariably leads to the 1960s Adam Adamant Lives TV series.)

Comment: Was it a movie? A series? Or maybe an episode of an anthology series like Twilight Zone or Outer Limits.

Comment: I'm really not sure, maybe an episode of "some series"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possibly an episode of the American TV show *Amazing Stories* entitled [Such Interesting Neighbors.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511116/)

Adam Ant plays Ted Hellenbeck who, along with his wife and son, arouse the suspicions of their new neighbors because of the Hellenbeck families odd behavior.

The script was based on the [short story of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Such_Interesting_Neighbors) by Jack Finney. I can't find a summary of the TV episode but according to the story summary the time traveling neighbors are from an era where a global war was about to happen but everyone sought to escape the war by going to the past.

The episode is available to view [at dailymotion.](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6hvy16)

Comment: Skimming through the episode on dailymotion this looks promising! The scene with the hat and water bowl happens at around the 11 minute mark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewf8V.png

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat similar to two TV plays from the anthology [Play For Today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_for_Today).   The first was called [The Flipside Of Dominick Hyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flipside_of_Dominick_Hide), followed by the sequel [Another Flip For Dominick](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083566/).

It isn't quite as you describe. Dominick is a future man who travels back and forth between his time and 1980. He isn't hiding out, but he does engage in certain forbidden activities that risk changing history, and is worried that the authorities will find out.   And in 1980 he poses as a member of a religious order, and dresses in a black jacket and a wide brimmed black hat.

Both episodes are on Youtube. I've skimmed through them, and don't see any part where he stares into a cauldron.  Maybe  that's a different film and you're conflating.

[image]

Comment: No sorry, not either of the flipside episodes, I only rewatch  them a few months ago